# System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: iqueryable, expression, custom-linq-providers, expressionvisitor

I'm trying to follow the instructions on [Creating an IQueryable LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx), but when I implement the classes which inherit from `ExpressionVisitor` as instructed I am told that ExpressionVisitor is inaccessible due to its protection level.  Am I missing something incredibly basic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class is sealed, stupidly enough. Use the ExpressionVisitor at the end of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx) post instead. I can definitely recommend that walk-through, btw, it's really comprehensive and helpful in every way.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm on my way to IQueryable goodness, but why on earth did the MSDN article want me to inherit a class that I couldn't?!

Comment: I honestly don't know, I faced the same idiocraticy when I was doing this about a year ago. Have fun building your provider!

Comment: What a brilliant set of tutorials - I'm on #4 and I've already got an awesome provider.  I guess you just can't rely on Microsoft to produce good tutorials themselves!

Comment: I fully agree, Matt rocks! What are you building a provider for, if I may ask?

Comment: You probably already know this but just in case you don't, .NET 4.0 now exposes the MS implementation of ExpressionVisitor and have extended it somewhat.

Comment: Sorry Banang, I must have missed your comment because I've just been redirected back here by the new answer. I was building and did indeed build a provider for my ORM, and it's pretty tasty now! :)

Comment: Useful to know. I am still supporting 3.5 codebases and I eventually came here because most examples were using the `ExpressionVisitor` class as it would be a valid base class. Good to know an alternative version exists.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 4.0, the Microsoft-provided implementation of `ExpressionVisitor` (built into the BCL) is no longer sealed.